# Как правильно закрепить header?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Работал вот в таком направлении:

```
/**
 * Прилипающий хеадер
 */
var sticky = $('.navbar-fixed-top');
var defTop = sticky.offset().top;

scrollSticky(sticky, defTop);

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    scrollSticky(sticky, defTop);
});

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    scrollSticky(sticky, defTop);
});

function scrollSticky(sticky, defTop) {
    if (defTop - ($('body').scrollTop() || $('html').scrollTop()) <= 0) {
        sticky.addClass("sticky-header-play");
        sticky.css("top", $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    } else {
        sticky.removeClass("sticky-header-play");
    }
}
```

Все работает все хорошо, за исключением, что на телефонах и в сафари прилипающая шапка не статична, как бы догоняет скролл. Тоесть если прокрутить страницу хеадер догонит нужное место где-то через пол секунды. Такое происходит только на телефонах и в сафари.

Если вы хотите предложить что то типа:

```
position: fixed
```

То это максимально плохое решение, так как при следующих стилях:

```
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 980px;
    height: 42px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4D8EC2 0px, #4989BF 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
}
```

если сжать страницу до появления нижнего скрола, все что будет в хеадере за рабочей областью будет обрезано.

Собственно подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел вот такой плагин: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed
Вроде все решает, не идеально, но лучшее, что есть.

Answer (score 1):

Этот CSS совершенно нормален.

```
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
top: 0px
```

Так даже в Twitterе сделана эта же верстка.

Чтобы понять почему преждевременная оптимизация зло возьмите httpd-access-log какого-нибудь среднего сайта и посчитайте число User-Agents. Их там будет несколько тысяч если не больше.

Все еще думаете что пытаться сделать сайт который выглядит совершенно одинаково на них всех это здравая идея?

И да, прикрепленная панель в большинстве случаев не нужна. Зачем навязывать кому-то какой-то кусок интерфейса?

Comment: 1) Тз  2) я перфекционист и у меня все должно работать на высшем уровне.